# Create a voting poll for specific posts wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have looking for a plugin tried out many the only plugin i found close to my requirements is WTI LIKE POST . Now it has options to create voting for specific categories like excluding option in it ..  I am looking to do something like that for only specific posts . Like creating a  poll on specific posts i choose .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Wp Poll. You can customize the same as per the requirement:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-polls/

Comment: This is  a poll to create for some random question i wanna create poll for just posts so that that most voted post can be selected